# Brownian Motion Probability calculation P[Z(s)<a, Z(t)<b]

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is there a closed form solution for $P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]$ 
where $Z$ is a Brownian motion and $0<a<b$ are constants?

In the post [Probability Brownian Motion - dependence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575740/probability-brownian-motion-dependence) the user Did gave the following answer to 
$P[Z(s)<0, Z(t)<0]$=$1/4$$+$$(1/2π)$arctan$(\sqrt s/(t-s))$

Following Did's approach I have tried as follows:

With $U$ and $V$ being standard normally distributed we have
$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=P[U\sqrt(s)<-a, U\sqrt(s)+V\sqrt(t-s)<-b]<=>$
$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=P[U<-a/\sqrt(s), U\sqrt(s/t)+V\sqrt((t-s)/t)<-b/\sqrt(t)]$

As $sin[m]^2+cos[m]^2=1=s/t+(t-s)/s$ we can rewrite
$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=P[U<-a/\sqrt(s), U sin[m]+V cos[m]<-b/\sqrt(t)]$

Note that as $0<\sqrt(s/t)$, $\sqrt((t-s)/t) <1$ implies that $0<m<\pi/2$.

Switching to polar coordinates, we define:

$U=r cos(\theta)$, $V=r sin[\theta]$,

this gives:

$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]$=$P[$$r cos[\theta]<-a/\sqrt(s)$, $r cos[\theta] sin[m]+r sin[\theta] cos[m]$$<$$-b/\sqrt(t)$]

$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=P[rcos[\theta]<-a/\sqrt(s), r sin[\theta+m]<-b/\sqrt(t)]$

As $a$, $b>0$ per assumption and $r>0$ as it is a radius, a necessary condition for both inequalities is $cos[\theta]<0$ and $sin[\theta+m]<0$. This implies

$P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]$$=$$P[r>-a/(\sqrt(s)/cos[\theta]), r>-b/(\sqrt(t)/sin[\theta+m])]$

These inequalities imply the following domains for $r$ and $\theta$

$b/\sqrt(t)<r<\infty$  and $\pi$$-$$m$$<$$\theta$$<$$3*\pi/2$

The question now is, which distribution can I assume for $\theta$ and r. Initially, I thought that $\theta$ is uniformly distributed (that's what I learned from Did's post) and that r is Rayleigh distributed. However, Excel simulations show me that this is wrong.

Does anyone know whether this problem can be solved analytically, or can it only be solved numerically, i.e. with simulations?

Comment: "Initially, I thought that θ is uniformly distributed (that's what I learned from Did's post) and that r is Rayleigh distributed. However, Excel simulations show me that this is wrong." Oh yeah? How so?

Comment: I used Excel's random function to compute 10000 events for $Z(s)$ and $Z(t)$ and counted the events that meet the condition $Z(s)<-a$ and $Z(t)<-b$. This gives me then the probability that I compared to the result that was given to me by the formula $Exp(b^2 t/2)(1/4 + (1/(2\pi)) arctan(\sqrt(s/(t−s)))$. This is the same approach that I used for testing your formula from the other post.

Comment: Where is the formula "Exp(b2t/2)(1/4+(1/(2π))arctan((√s/(t−s)))" coming from?

Comment: It is the solution to the integral  <br/> $$\int_b^\infty \int_{\pi-m}^{3\pi/2} (1/2\pi)*rExp(-r^2/2)d\theta dr$$  <br/> My understanding is that this is the integral that one obtains after switching to polar coordinates for two independent normally distributed variables.

Comment: Except that this yields Exp(-b^2/2), not Exp(b^2t/2).

Comment: You are right. There is a typo in my last two comments. The integral I worked with is<br/>  $\int\limits_{b/\sqrt(t)}^{\infty} \int\limits_{\pi-m}^{3\pi/2} (1/(2\pi))rExp(-r^2/2) d\theta dr$<br/>  The solution that I used includes the expression $Exp(-(b^2/t)(1/2))$  <br/>

Comment: @Did: in the post "Expected Value of Normal CDF" you commented "@RayKoopman As explained several times in the couple of recent near duplicates on MO and MSE and StatsSE, for some finite t  there is no explicit formula. – DidAug 3 '13 at 19:42 "  I searched the MSE for these references but I could not find any references mentioned. I think this suggests that my problem can be solved numerically, only. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=\int_a^{+\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{x-b}{\sqrt{t-s}}\right)\,\varphi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\,\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{s}}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I think I understood the idea. After playing around with your result I would arrived at a slightly different solution:   $P[Z(s)<-a, Z(t)<-b]=\int_{-\infty}^{-a/\sqrt(s)}\Phi(-(b+x\sqrt(s))/\sqrt(t-s))\phi(x)dx$. Anyways, thanks a lot for answering all my questions!

Comment: Good. Exercise: the formula in your comment is a more complicated version of the one in my answer.

Comment: Helpful exercise! I think you get from my formula to your formula by a change of variable, i.e. $\sqrt(s) x=-y$. Where the $y$ used in this comment equals the $x$ in your comment.